# Getting error with subprocess while running aws s3 cp: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aws'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am able to execute this command successfully from command line and it copies the desired csv to the s3 bucket `aws s3 cp /Users/kaswani/tips.csv s3://dplearn/`

But, when I try to run the same from within python using subprocess it throws error:
`subprocess.check_output(['aws','s3','cp','/Users/kaswani/tips.csv','s3://dplearn/'])`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/kaswani/anaconda/envs/aws/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/Users/kaswani/anaconda/envs/aws/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/Users/kaswani/anaconda/envs/aws/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Users/kaswani/anaconda/envs/aws/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aws'
```

I have not been able to debug it. Subprocess works just fine for basic commands like ls etc

Comment: Are you running the python program from the same command line? Maybe there is something else going on in your program. You should be able to write a 2 line .py file (just add `import subprocess` and the line that you show) that demonstrates the problem. When run from the command line, does it fail?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This debugging method worked. Probably some bug with the way I was importing stuff.

Comment: In the meantime to make things work, I used os.system() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using, shell=True makes is work, i.e. subprocess.check_output(['aws','s3','cp','/Users/kaswani/tips.csv','s3://dplearn/'], shell=True)